# How to check if the key is an unsaved value in NHibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I am creating a model binder to use with asp.net mvc. This is what I got so far:

```
public class ModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        PersistentClass mapping = DataAccess.Configuration.GetClassMapping(modelType);
        if(mapping != null)
        {
            ValueProviderResult value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(mapping.IdentifierProperty.Name);
            if(value != null)
            {
                object keyValue = value.ConvertTo(mapping.Key.Type.ReturnedClass);
                if(mapping.Key.**** IsUnsavedValue(value) ****)
                {
                    return DataAccess.Session.Load(modelType, keyValue);
                }
            }
        }
        return base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, modelType);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to check if the value of an entity key is unsaved in NHibernate? i.e. What would I replace the `**** IsUnsavedValue(value) ****` with?

Or is there a way to get the value of the unsaved-value of the id in the mapping file. i.e. The **** in the following:

```
<id unsaved-value="****">
```

Comment: Using persitent entities as viewmodel is very difficult to make secure. Question: What is an entity key?

Comment: @Paco I agree that there are security issues. I am using this to quickly generate the backend (not exposed to the public). The key I am looking for is the <id> value mapped in the mapping file. I will update the quetion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the `mapping.Identifier.NullValue`

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thank you!